# Make CruiseControl.NET projects show what changes were made since last run

Tags: mercurial, cruisecontrol.net

I have a chain of CruiseControl.NET targets like the ones below.  The first project pulls the changesets from a repository and runs fast unit tests on these changes.  If these unit tests succeed, the full product is built, and if that succeeds, a large test suite is run on the newly compiled product.

```xml
<project name="pullAndRunUnitTests">
    <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger seconds="300"/>
    </triggers>
    <sourcecontrol repo="$(Repo)" type="hg" revertModifications="true"/>
    <tasks>
        <nant>
            <targetList>
                <target>unitTests</target>
            </targetList>
        </nant>
    </tasks>
</project>
<project name="product">
    <triggers>
        <projectTrigger project="pullAndRunUnitTests"/>
    </triggers>
    <tasks>
        <nant>
            <targetList>
                <target>all</target>
            </targetList>
        </nant>
    </tasks>
</project>
<project name="regressionTests">
    <triggers>
        <projectTrigger project="product"/>
    </triggers>
    <tasks>
        <nant>
            <targetList>
                <target>regressiontests</target>
            </targetList>
        </nant>
    </tasks>
</project>
```

The problem with this setup is that only the unit tests will correctly identify who broke the the build;  if succeeding projects in the chain break, it can get hard to identify who/what actually made things break.

Is there a way to make CruiseControl.NET projects show what changes were made since the last time they were run, or alternatively, "inherit changes" from the projects that trigger them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to let the depending CCNET project "inherit" the changes:

1. Add a [Modification Writer Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Writer_Task) to project `pullAndRunUnitTests`
2. Add a [Modification Reader Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Reader_Task) to project `product`

Do the same for `product`-`regressionTests` dependency:

1. Modification Writer Task to project `product`
2. Modification Reader Task to project `regressionTests`

Like this:

```xml
<project name="pullAndRunUnitTests">
    ...
    <tasks>
        <modificationWriter>
            <filename>changes-product.xml</filename>
            <path>..</path>
            <appendTimeStamp>True</appendTimeStamp>
        </modificationWriter>
        <nant>...</nant>
    </tasks>
</project>
<project name="product">
    ...
    <tasks>
        <modificationReader>
            <filename>changes-product.xml</filename>
            <path>..</path>
            <deleteAfterRead>True</deleteAfterRead>
        </modificationReader>
        <modificationWriter>
            <filename>changes-regressionTests.xml</filename>
            <path>..</path>
            <appendTimeStamp>True</appendTimeStamp>
        </modificationWriter>
        <nant>...</nant>
    </tasks>
</project>
<project name="regressionTests">
    ...
    <tasks>
        <modificationReader>
            <filename>changes-regressionTests.xml</filename>
            <path>..</path>
            <deleteAfterRead>True</deleteAfterRead>
        </modificationReader>
        <nant>...</nant>
    </tasks>
</project>
```